# CSS: line break inside :after

Tags: html, css

I want to split some text inside an `:after` pseudo-element of label (which get its content from `data-` attribute). I tried with `word-break` and also with `width`, `max-width` and `position:relative`, but nothing works...

HTML:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkme" id="checkme" />
    <label for="checkme" data-content="Some very long text that should be split into two lines like br tag"></label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.checkbox {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    position:relative;
}

.checkbox:not(:only-child):not(:first-child) {
    margin:10px 0 0 0;
}

.checkbox input {
    display:none;
}

.checkbox label {
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
    width:13px;
    height:13px;
    border:1px solid #383838;
}

.checkbox label:after {
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14.5px;
    color:#383838;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    left:calc(100% + 7px);
    content:attr(data-content);
    cursor:text;
    white-space:pre;
    word-break:break-all;
    top:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(0,-50%);
    -moz-transform:translate(0,-50%);
    transform:translate(0,-50%);
    /* max-width and width not working... */
    max-width:160px !important;
    width:160px !important;
}

.checkbox input:checked ~ label:before {
    display:block;
}

.checkbox input:not(:checked) ~ label:before {
    display:none;
}

.checkbox label:before {
    font-size:16px;
    color:#383838;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -moz-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    pointer-events:none;
    margin:0;
    width:auto;
    content:"X";
    font-family:Arial;
}
```

How can I make it right (or: what did I do wrong)?

Thank you.

Comment: Change your white-space:pre; to white-space:wrap;

Answer (score 0):

Try this: add `top:170%` and `white-space:wrap` as suggested by @Carol McKay

```css
.checkbox {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    position:relative;
}

.checkbox:not(:only-child):not(:first-child) {
    margin:10px 0 0 0;
}

.checkbox input {
    display:none;
}

.checkbox label {
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
    width:13px;
    height:13px;
    border:1px solid #383838;
}

.checkbox label:after {
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14.5px;
    color:#383838;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    left:calc(100% + 7px);
    content:attr(data-content);
    cursor:text;
    white-space:wrap;
    word-break:break-all;
    top:170%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(0,-50%);
    -moz-transform:translate(0,-50%);
    transform:translate(0,-50%);
    /* max-width and width not working... */
    max-width:160px !important;
    width:160px !important;
}

.checkbox input:checked ~ label:before {
    display:block;
}

.checkbox input:not(:checked) ~ label:before {
    display:none;
}

.checkbox label:before {
    font-size:16px;
    color:#383838;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -moz-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    pointer-events:none;
    margin:0;
    width:auto;
    content:"X";
    font-family:Arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkme" id="checkme" />
    <label for="checkme" data-content="Some very long text that should be split into two lines like br tag"></label>
</div>
```